# ATM finder application in android

Tags: android, android-maps

I am trying to develop ATM finder application in Android. I am equipped with how to get my location and to access map. Can someone help me to find out ATMs on map?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchRequests) to find nearby places. One of the [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) is "atm".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google PLACE api...

Which will allow you to find nearest ATM, HOSPITALS... etc..

You can get **LATITUDE** and **LONGITUDE**  from its service and can display in your map

here is [link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) Hope this will help  you